# Linear transformation matrix given two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm having trouble with this problem.

Given two vectors

$ \overrightarrow{v} = \left( \begin{matrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{matrix} \right) $

$ \overrightarrow{v'} = \left( \begin{matrix} v'_1 \\ v'_2 \end{matrix} \right) $

Given that T is a linear transformation

$ T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $

And that

$ \overrightarrow{v}' = T(\overrightarrow{v}) $

Find the matrix T which represents the linear transformation.

I tried to express this in matrix form as

$ \left( \begin{matrix} v'_1 \\ v'_2 \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} T_{11} & T_{12} \\ T_{21} & T_{22} \end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{matrix} \right) $

But i don't know how to continue, should i expand the matrix multiplication in the RHS and isolate the T's?

I have an example of this , suppose

$ \overrightarrow{v} = \left( \begin{matrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{matrix} \right) $

$ \overrightarrow{v'} = \left( \begin{matrix} 6 \\ -1 \end{matrix} \right) $

How would this be? I don't know how to continue

Comment: The matrix representation of a linear transformation depends on an basis and from knowing the image of the basis. Here we don't have an explicit basis, though one could use the canonical basis, but we still don't have the image of this. I think that this is the problem that you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not have a unique solution. For example,
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 0 \\ 
1 & -1 \\ 
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 \\ 
3 \\ 
\end{array}\right)
=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
6 \\ 
-1 \\ 
\end{array}\right)
\ \ \ 
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 2 \\ 
4 & -3 \\ 
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 \\ 
3 \\ 
\end{array}\right)
=\left(\begin{array}{c}
6 \\ 
-1 \\ 
\end{array}\right)
$$